# Why is SAT the complement of TAUTOLOGY?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, satisfiability

I am studying some Discrete Mathematics lecture notes and am trying to understand the claim that SAT is the complement of TAUTOLOGY.
(I have posted on this SE site because I think that the root of my issue is a potential misunderstanding of logic.)

I have studied the definitions of SAT, NOT-SAT, TAUTOLOGY, and NOT-TAUTOLOGY (below).

---

SAT: given a Boolean formula $\phi$, determine if $\phi$ is satisfiable (that is, if there is an assignment of truth values to the literals in $\phi$, such that the evaluation of $\phi$ is TRUE).
Alternatively, one could consider SAT as the set of all Boolean formulae which are satisfiable.

NOT-SAT: given a Boolean formula $\gamma$, determine if $\gamma$ is not satisfiable (that is, if, for all assignments of truth values to the literals in $\gamma$, the evaluation of $\gamma$ is FALSE).
Alternatively, one could consider NOT-SAT as the set of all Boolean formulae which are not satisfiable.

TAUTOLOGY: given a Boolean formula $\epsilon$, determine if $\epsilon$ is satisfiable for **every** assignment of truth values to the literals in $\epsilon$ (that is, if, for all assignments of truth values to the literals in $\epsilon$, the evaluation of $\epsilon$ is TRUE).
Alternatively, one could consider TAUTOLOGY as the set of all Boolean formulae which are tautologies.

NOT-TAUTOLOGY: given a Boolean formula $\delta$, determine if $\delta$ is not a tautology (that is, if there is an assignment of truth values to the literals of $\delta$, such that the evaluation of $\delta$ is FALSE).
Alternatively, one could consider NOT-TAUTOLOGY as the set of all Boolean formulae which are not tautologies.

---

**MY ISSUE:**

I am not sure if the following logic is sound:

If the *yes* answers for SAT are changed to *no*, then SAT is transformed to NOT-TAUTOLOGY, and vice versa.
If the *yes* answers for TAUTOLOGY are changed to *no*, then TAUTOLOGY is transformed to NOT-SAT, and vice versa.
Hence SAT is equivalent to NOT-TAUTOLOGY, and TAUTOLOGY is equivalent to NOT-SAT.

I would appreciate comments/answers which help me to check if the above reasoning is correct or not.

---

Having read the comments, I now have a new issue. *(NB: this issue is rooted in the fact that I don't think I fully understand the definition of the complement of a decision problem.)*

I understand that: $A$ is a tautology $\iff \neg A$ is unsatisfiable.

Now, my lecture notes state that, given a decision problem $X$, its complement $\bar X$ is the same decision problem with the yes and no answers reversed.

(In the context of SAT, I understand a *yes* answer to be a Boolean formula which is satisfiable, and a *no* answer to be a Boolean formula which is unsatisfiable.)

According to the lecture notes' definition of 'complement' we can define SAT and NOT-SAT as follows:

SAT: given a Boolean formula $B$, if there's an assignment of truth values to the literals in $B$ such that $B$ evaluates to TRUE, then $B$ results in a *yes* answer.
Else (i.e., if there is no assignment of truth values to the literals in $B$ such that $B$ evaluates to TRUE) $B$ results in a *no* answer.

NOT-SAT: given a Boolean formula $B$, if there's an assignment of truth values to the literals in $B$ such that $B$ evaluates to TRUE, then $B$ results in a *no* answer.
Else (i.e., if there is no assignment of truth values to the literals in $B$ such that $B$ evaluates to TRUE) $B$ results in a *yes* answer.

Now, assuming that TAUTOLOGY is the complement of SAT, TAUTOLOGY should be equivalent to NOT-SAT.
However, this is the definition of TAUTOLOGY:

Given a Boolean formula $B$, if there's an assignment of truth values to the literals in $B$ such that $B$ evaluates to FALSE, then $B$ results in a *no* answer.
Else (i.e., if, for all assignments of truth values to the literals in $B$, $B$ evaluates to TRUE) $B$ results in a *yes* answer.

At first glance, this might look equivalent to NOT-SAT, but it is not - the FALSE and TRUE are reversed.
Can anyone explain why this is, please? It is, I think, the core issue which is hindering my progress in understanding why SAT is the complement of TAUTOLOGY.

Comment: A formula $A$ is a *tautology* **iff** its negation : $\lnot A$ is not *satisfiable*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA (and CKKOY): I recommend not using **any** when you mean **every** in this kind of context (as **any** can be read as meaning **some**, turning the universal quantifier you intended into an existential quantifier). This is possibly the source of CKKOY's difficulty.

Comment: @RobArthan That is a helpful comment which I will keep in mind. However, it was not the source of my difficulty.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Why does it follow that $\neg A$ is false for every assignment?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I now understand why a formula $A$ is a _tautology_ *iff* its negation $\neg A$ is _unsatisfiable_. However, I don't see the link between this and the statement: SAT is the complement of TAUTOLOGY. 'Why don't I see this link?' you might ask. The reason is that I am really struggling to understand *the definition of the complement of a decision problem*. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If $A$ is *true* for the assignment $v$, then the negation of $A$, i.e. $\lnot A$, is **not** true, i.e. *false*, for that assignment. Ergo, if $A$ is true for every assignment, then $\lnot A$ is false for every assignment.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, thank you. I understand your most recent comment. However, I'm still trying to make the link between this and why SAT (the *set* of all satisfiable Boolean formulae) is the complement of TAUTOLOGY (the *set* of all tautologies). These sets don't seem to complement each other in my mind!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46760/discussion-between-ckkoy-and-mauro-allegranza).

Comment: Indeed. I had that realisation myself. So, why do my lecture notes state that SAT is the complement of TAUT??

Comment: We have to consider "complement", as you said, with *yes* and *no* swapped... Is $A$ in TAUT ? If the answer is NO, then $\lnot A$ is in SAT.

Comment: Hmm...I thought we consider the same decision problem with the _yes_ and _no_ answers swapped (not consider the complement with the _yes_ and _no_ answers swapped).  Am I becoming unnecessarily confused, or does my reasoning make sense?

Answer (score 3):

A formula $A$ is a *tautology* if it is true with every assignment.

A formula $A$ is *satisfiable* if there is at least an assignemnt $v$ such that $A$ is true for $v$.

If $A$ is true for the assignment $v$, then its negation, $¬A$, is false for that assignment.

A formula $A$ is a *tautology* **iff** its negation, $¬A$, is not *satisfiable*.

The [complement of a decision problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(complexity)) :

> is the decision problem resulting from reversing the yes and no answers.

Thus, in a nutshell, if the answer to the problem "is $A$ in TAUT ?" is **NO**, then $¬A$ is in SAT.

More precisely, the problem of determining if some formula $A$ is not a tautology is thus equivalent to the problem of determining if the negation of the formula, $¬A$, is satisfiable.

---

It seems to me that it is only a terminological issue. Compare with :

- Sanjeev Arora & Boaz Barak, [Computational complexity : A Modern Approach](https://books.google.it/books?id=nGvI7cOuOOQC&pg=PA55) (2009), page 55:

> Now we define some additional complexity classes related to $\text {P}$ and $\text {NP}$.
>
> If $L ⊆ \{ 0, 1 \}^∗$ is a language, then we denote by $\overline L$ the *complement* of $L$.
>
> We make the following definition: $\text {coNP} = \{ L \mid \overline L ∈ \text {NP} \}$.
>
> $\text {coNP}$ is not the complement of the class $\text {NP}$. The following
> is an example of a $\text {coNP}$ language: $\overline {\text {SAT} } = \{ \varphi \mid \varphi \text { is not satisfiable} \}$.

The *decision problems* (or languages) are complementary : not the corresponding classes of formulae.

Comment: The answer is helpful. Should the last line of the excerpt from Sanjeev Arora & Boaz Barak read '$\text{SAT}=\{\varphi \mid \varphi \text{ is satisfiable}\}$'?

Comment: @CalebOwusu-Yianoma It's correct the way it is now; there's a line above SAT, and that line is common notation for the [complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Definition) of a set.